# How to remove all html tags except bold, italic, underline and new line?

Tags: regex

I am not that good with regular expression so I am seeking help for this one.

I would like to know what is a regular expression for removing all html tags except for the following.

1. Bold
2. Italic
3. Underline
4. New Line

Thanks guys. hope you could help me on this one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a very popular answer here for a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1046610

Answer (score 2):

Jokes apart from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1046610), don't try to parse HTML with Regex, use a HTML parser. It will make your life easy.

Google something or search here on SO about "HTML parser" + your language of choice.

Comment: `...dear lord help us how can anyone survive this scourge using regex to parse HTML...`, we are doomed!

Answer (score 1):

replace regex with empty string `<[]>.*?</[]>`
and collect into `[]` all include tags, for example `<[mas]>.*?</[mas]>` capture `<m>anything</m>` `<a>anything</a>` `<s>anything</s>`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why other answers think you need to parse the HTML. You just need to replace some patterns and not others. So you use a callback function for the regex replacement...

```
var keep = {
    b: true,
    i: true,
    u: true,
    br: true
};

html.replace(/<\/?([a-z]+) ?[^>]*>/g, function(wholeMatch, tagName)
{
    if (keep[tagName]) {
        return wholeMatch;
    }

    return '';
});
```

Comment: This example is case sensitive, and could be modified to keep attributes or not depending on the tag as well.

Answer (score -1):

- You can use regex first to replace the Bold , Italic , Underline Tags
  to Temp string
- Then Replace all html tags in to plain text
- Replace temp string back in to Bold, Italic, Underline tag

Below is the link with detailed one with code.

http://techierocks.com/2018/07/remove-html-tags-css-styling-except-bold-italic-underline-new-line.html